# Lua loadfile() and Call a Function Defined in the File By Name

Tags: lua

In Lua how can I use loadfile() to load a function like

```
function test() print('test') end
```

And then execute it by name? For example if I `loadfile()` then `pcall()` the contents of the file are executed. How can I then call test()?

Edit: the function 'test' may be any arbitrary function defined in the file.

Edit2: in a sandboxed environment?

Comment: `assert(loadfile("test_func.lua"))(); test()` should work as test() becomes global function after executing content of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Egors comment turned me onto this solution; `loadstring/loadfile` returns a 'chunk' which can be executed. Any functions define there are added to _G, the global environment. The function `setfenv(function, environment)` adds functions defined in a function to the supplied environment. The function can then be called by name. Confusing? Yes, see this example:

```
Lua 5.1.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> string_a = "function a(msg) print(msg) end"
> func_a = loadstring(string_a)
> env = { print = print }
> setfenv(func_a, env)
> pcall(func_a)
> for k,v in pairs(env) do print(k,v) end
    print   function: 0x19a5a40
    a   function: 0x19c9ed0
> env['a']('test')
test
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make a function named test? Then this is how:

```
   function test()
            print('test')
   end
```

and call it by:

```
test()
```

if you want to load that from another file lets say the above code is in a file called "scripts.scriptTest" then calling it to your main file would be like:

```
local scriptTest = require("scripts.scriptTest")
scriptTest.test()
```

Comment: This caches so if you change `test` and rerun  the old version runs. Which isn't good for development...